# How can I delete one field with same name in mongodb 3.2?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57b" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "exam", "score" : 74.20010837299897 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57c" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 96.76851542258362 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57d" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 21.33260810416115 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57e" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 44.31667452616328 }
```

given above is the database in json format.I want to delete the field(homework) with the low score.
db.grades(######)
please write the solution in place of ######
after deletion my database should look like the data given below

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57b" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "exam", "score" : 74.20010837299897 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57c" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 96.76851542258362 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb57e" }, "student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework", "score" : 44.31667452616328 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):

```
db.students.findAndModify({
     query: {"student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework"},
     sort: {"score": 1},
     remove: true
})
```

In MongoDB 3.2 you can also use [`findOneAndDelete`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/):

```
db.students.findOneAndDelete(
     {"student_id" : 1, "type" : "homework"},
     {sort: {"score": 1}}
)
```

These queries would:

1. Filter all documents based on the `student_id` and `type`
2. Sort documents based on the `score` ascendingly and then act on the
   first value after sort, which is the one with minimum score
3. Delete the document with minimum homework score

I'm not an expert of PyMongo, but you can use the [`find_one_and_delete`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_delete) method to achieve the same in python:

```
filter_by_student_and_type = {'student_id' : 1, 'type' : 'homework'}
sort_by_score = [('score', pymongo.ASCENDING )]
db.students.find_one_and_delete(filter_by_student_and_type, sort=sort_by_score)
```

Comment: thnak you so much :) :) !!